# Where clause on collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using the BAGA code from Julie Lerman's DbContext book.  I want to recreate the following SQL query in LINQ and put the results in a List collections and am having problems.
http://learnentityframework.com/downloads/

```
SELECT * FROM baga.Locations d
LEFT JOIN Lodgings l ON d.LocationID = l.destination_id
WHERE d.Country = 'usa'
AND (l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5 or l.MilesFromNearestAirport is null)
```

So, in English, get all locations (destinations) that are in the USA and include all the related lodgings where MilesFromNearestAirport > 5

The syntax doesn't compile but I was hoping for something similar to below

```
var dests = context.Destinations
  .Where(d => d.Country == "USA" && d.Lodgings.Where(l => l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5))
  .Select(d => d)
  .ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The approach is wrong because of the left join. You need to do something similiar: .Where(d => d.Country == "USA" && (d.Lodgings.Count == 0 || d.Lodgings.Any(l => l.MilesFromNearestAirport == null || l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5)) This should retrieve the correct Locations. When accessing the lodgings, the same expression in the lodgings where clause will need to be used to retrieve the applicable lodgings. As far as I know, entity framework only supports inner join. On another note, this query would be pretty simple in nhibernate.

Comment: Neither of these solutions work.  Shelakel, have you used NHibernate much?  Would you recommend it over EF?

Comment: Just curious...why do you need .Select(d => d) here. If you remove this it's just a straight forward lambda expression and might work. Another quick Q. It depends on personal preference, but you could close the brackets at the && part and replace the && with another .Where(...).

Comment: Its a while since I wrote this but my original code didn't work and I was just learning Linq so please ignore it!  I would probably now use some kind of groupjoin with a where clause for null & > 5.  The original Select(d => d) seems pretty pointless to me ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Sampath says, this is normally done with navigation properties but I believe that his code does not exactly do what you want. This (I think) is closer:

```
var dests = context.Destinations
           .Where(d => d.Country == "USA")
           .Select(d => 
               new { d,
                     RemoteLodgings = d.Lodgings
                         .Where(l => l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5)}
           .ToList();
```

But it still does not do what you want if I take your requirement to the letter. You want the location with the lodgings *included*, i.e. the navigation properties loaded partly. This can be convenient when the entities are to be serialized and sent to a (web) client in one package. (Although the method above would be OK for that too).

But it is possible to make a collection with partly loaded navigation properties.

The book, at page 40, shows how you can partly load navigation properties of a single entity (in short: `context.Entry(entity).Collection(e => e.Children).Query().Where(condition)`. But as said, that's only one instance. It's not the best method to do that for a collection of entities.

The funny thing is (as a colleague of mine found out), you can easily do it for a collection of entities by loading the required collection elements into the context separately:

```
var lodgings = context.Lodgings
              .Where(l => l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5 
                       && l.Destination.Country == "USA")
              .ToList();
```

Now if you loop through `context.Destinations.Where(d => d.Country == "USA")` you will see that their lodgings are loaded with the ones "`>5`". Probably because at this point EF executed relationship fixup. (Lazy loading disabled, because lazy loading will fully load the navigation properties).

**Edit** (after your comment)
I couldn't agree more when you say it is a bit of a hack. Actually, I forgot to mention that in the first place. The problem is that the whole mechanism collapses when lazy loading happens to be activated by someone who's not aware of the what the code is for. I don't like code that depends on the state in a way that is not obvious. So I would always prefer the first approach.

Comment: Saying that I have improved your code slightly by removing var lodgings and replacing .ToList() with Load() as I guess that is all I need to do.  A little happier with it now actually.

Comment: Oh, and I had to remove the virtual keyword to switch off lazy loading (like you said)

Comment: Also, what are your thoughts on just using stored procs for this purpose rather than entity framework?

Comment: Agree!! If this is something that is performance-sensitive you could consider a stored procedure. I would not opt for it to quickly, because I would prefer to have one code base. Of course if there are more sprocs it could be a viable option.

Comment: I find the premise of lazy loading really good in some scenarios (working on data locally etc) but I don't want to do that because I want to return JSON data to the client (as you correctly guessed) so I need to retrieve larger chunks of data in one go.

Comment: More on this technique here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is done **using navigation properties** which are loaded when you get the entity.

However you can also do this with the following:

```
(from d in baga.Locations
 from l in Lodgings
 where (d.LocationID == l.destination_id)
 where (d.Country = 'usa' && (l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5 || l.MilesFromNearestAirport == null))
 select d)
 .ToList();
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Sorry, the result set is incorrect.  This neither restricts MilesFromNearestAirport > 5 nor includes those records where there is no related Lodgings files.  Is it just me or is LINQ just painful for such simple sql such as this?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the LINQ join?

```
 var res = from d in context.Destinations
           join l in context.Lodgings on d.LocationID equals l.destination_id
           where (l.MilesFromNearestAirport > 5 || l.MilesFromNearestAirport == null)
                 && d.Country = "usa"
           select new {
                     Destination = d,
                     Location = l
                  }
```