# Left join using Linq without the "messy" join

Tags: linq-to-entities

A Cost is linked to an AnsweredQuestion in a PropertySurvey via QuestionID and AnswerID foreign keys.
A Cost may also be linked to an AnsweredQuestion in the same PropertySurvey via the UnitsQuestionID and again via the ReplacementQuestionID.
Here is the query as an inner join - written in a way that avoids the join syntax that @CraigStuntz [regards as "messy"](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/)

```
var propertyCosts = from aq in answeredQuestions
    from a in aq.Answers
    from c in costs
    where aq.QuestionID == c.QuestionID && a.ID == c.AnswerID
    from uq in answeredQuestions
    where uq.QuestionID == c.UnitsQuestionID 
                        && uq.PropertySurveyID == aq.PropertySurveyID
    from rq in answeredQuestions
    where rq.QuestionID == c.ReplacementQuestionID 
                        && rq.PropertySurveyID == aq.PropertySurveyID
    select new PropertyCost(aq.Question.Text, 
    a.Text, 
    c.Amount, 
    uq.IntegerAnswer.GetValueOrDefault(1), 
    rq.IntegerAnswer.GetValueOrDefault(0));
```

Is it possible to rewrite this with left joins to UnitQuestion and ReplacementQuestion without that `DefaultIfEmpty` stuff?

Comment: If answers are already linked to questions why does the cost need to be linked to a question and answer, surely you can just link to the question?

Comment: If the question is "Roof Replacement Required?" and the answer is "Yes" then there is a cost specified by c.Amount. If the answer is "No" then there are no costs.

Comment: But a UnitQuestion contains the value in its IntegerAnswer property - so no link to a separate answer in that relationship

Comment: Ignoring the UnitQuestion and replacementQuestion.  If a cost is associated with an answer and the answer is associated with with a question, surely for that case there is no need to link to a question, the foreign key just needs to link AnswerId.

Comment: The cost is associated with a question and an answer. Answers have a many to many relationship with questions. So "Yes" is a valid answer to many questions. If the question is "Is the roof in good condition?" and the answer is "Yes" then there is no cost.

Comment: What about UnitQuestion and ReplacementQuestion are the many-many, 1-many or 1-1?

Comment: One to many. A cost can have 1 UnitQuestion. A UnitQuestion can be linked to many Costs. Same relationship for ReplacementQuestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Make this problem less complicated to explain by abstracting the inner join 
//that we always need.
//For efficiency this should probably be put back in line
var A = from aq in answeredQuestions
        from a in aq.Answers
        from c in costs
        where aq.QuestionID == c.QuestionID && a.ID == c.AnswerID
        select new
        {
            QuestionText = aq.Question.Text,
            AnswerText = a.Text,
            Amount = c.Amount,
            PropertySurveyID = aq.PropertySurveyID,
            PropertySurvey = aq.PropertySurvey,
            UnitsQuestionID = c.UnitsQuestionID,
            UnitsQuestion = c.UnitsQuestion
        };


//This is how to do it using the explicit join keyword
var B = from a in A
        join lj in answeredQuestions on
            new { 
                   a.PropertySurveyID, 
                   UnitsQuestionID = a.UnitsQuestionID.GetValueOrDefault(0) 
                }
            equals new { 
                          lj.PropertySurveyID, 
                          UnitsQuestionID = lj.QuestionID 
                       }
            into unitQuestions
        from uq in unitQuestions.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new PropertyCost(a.QuestionText,
                    a.AnswerText,
                    a.Amount,
                    uq == null ? 1 : uq.IntegerAnswer.GetValueOrDefault(1));

//I thought this might do it but the filter on the navigational property 
//means it's equivalent to an inner join
var C = from a in A
        from uq in a.PropertySurvey
                    .AnsweredQuestions
                    .Where(x => x.QuestionID == a.UnitsQuestionID)
        select new PropertyCost(a.QuestionText,
                    a.AnswerText,
                    a.Amount,
                    uq == null ? 1 : uq.IntegerAnswer.GetValueOrDefault(1));

//This is the solution
//Back to the basics described by @CraigStuntz
//Just that we have to navigate further to get to the Units value
//Is this less "messy" than a join? Not sure. Maybe if you can think in Linq...
var D = from a in A
        select new PropertyCost
        (
            a.QuestionText,
            a.AnswerText,
            a.Amount,
            a.PropertySurvey
                .AnsweredQuestions
                .Where(x => x.QuestionID == a.UnitsQuestionID)
                .FirstOrDefault() == null
            ?
            1
            : a.PropertySurvey
                .AnsweredQuestions
                .Where(x => x.QuestionID == a.UnitsQuestionID)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .IntegerAnswer.GetValueOrDefault(1)
        );

//And here I have further refined it by putting the initial inner join back 
//inline and using the let keyword define how to retrieve the unit question. 
//This makes it much more readable:

var E = from aq in answeredQuestions
        from a in aq.Answers
        from c in costs
        let unitquestion = aq.PropertySurvey
            .AnsweredQuestions
            .Where(x => x.QuestionID == c.UnitsQuestionID)
            .FirstOrDefault()
        where aq.QuestionID == c.QuestionID && a.ID == c.AnswerID
        select new 
        {
            QuestionText = aq.Question.Text,
            AnswerText = a.Text,
            UnitCost = c.Amount,
            NumUnits = unitquestion == null ? 1 : unitquestion.IntegerAnswer ?? 1,
        };
```

Took me a long time to get this. I still think in sql and I can't help but be tempted to [Use Views in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17465477/150342) instead. Please note I have simplified this to show only the first left join to UnitQuestion

Answer (score 0):

In order to follow Craig Stuntz you need to have associations that your logic can follow.

So to model your Many-Many you would have an intermediate table that had a 1-Many association back to Questions and Answers. You could use Cost here and have a zero cost for no cost.

So

Question(QuestionId)  1 -> 1..* Cost(QuestionId)
Answer(AnswerId) 1 -> 1..* Cost(AnswerId)
Question(QuestionId) 1 -> 0..* Cost(UnitQuestionId)
Question(QuestionId) 1 -> 0..* Cost(ReplacementQuestionId)

Then in your model create the associations

```
Question (Property = Costs) -- (Property = Question) Costs
Question (no mapping) -- (Property = UnitQuestion) Costs
Question (no mapping) -- (Property = ReplacementQuestion) Costs
Answer (Property = Costs) -- (Property = Answer) Costs
```

This query should match the behaviour of your query.

```
from aq in answeredQuestions
from c in aq.Costs
select new PropertyCost(aq.Question.Text, 
                        c.Answer.Text, 
                        c.Amount, 
                        c.UnitQuestion == null ? 0 : c.UnitQuestion.IntegerAnswer
                        c.ReplacementQuestion == null ? 0 : c.ReplacementQuestion.IntegerAnswer
```

Comment: I now think the problem is not with my navigational properties or the type of relationship. The problem is that the sql equivalent is a left join with an additional constraint on the join. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14740121/150342 and my answer