# Improve linq query speed using join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I'm not used with linq. I use EF 4.0. I'm always using lambda expression to get my data like this:

```
List<User> users = db.Users
                        .Include(u => u.Licences)
                        .Include(u => u.Licences.Select(l => l.LicenceProducts.Select(lp => lp.Product)))
                        .Include(u => u.UserAddress)
                        .Include(u => u.Contact)
                        .Include(u => u.User2)
                        .Include(u => u.SupportProducts)
                        .Where(u => u.Type != (int)UserType.Admin)
                        .OrderBy(u => u.Name)
                        .ToList();
```

Unfortunately, it takes a lot of time to execute. So, I want to change it by using left joins but I'm not understanding correctly the way joins are working in Linq.

Here's what I tried:

```
users = from user in db.Users
        join licence in db.Licences on user.UserID equals licence.UserID
        join licenceProduct in db.LicenceProducts on licence.LicenceID equals licenceProduct.LicenceID...;
```

The type that it returns, is not the same as it was previously (List)

I also tried this but I have the same problem

```
users = db.Users
    .Join(db.Licences, lic => lic.UserID, user => user.UserID, (user, lic) => new { user, lic })
```

Comment: ensure you have indexes in your db.

Comment: I have indexes in my db. I just want to know how to use joins. I'm sure that it'il speed up the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins don't do the same as `Include`. `Include`s tell EF to populate associated navigation properties off the entity that's in the main query. Joins, however, only execute a SQL joins, but don't populate anything.

You typically use joins if you want to filter on properties in child or parent objects. Like `join c in Contacts ... where c.Name == "..."` – this only returns `Users` without any contacts populated. The SQL `SELECT` clause only contains User columns. (Well, assuming you only select distinct users).

`Include`s also produce SQL joins, but at the same time put all columns of the included entities in the `SELECT` clause. The query result set is used to materialize all included entities. When there are many `Include`s, this result will blow up incredibly in width and length. In width, because it selects all columns of all included entities. In length because each included child collection *multiplies* the result set by its number of rows.

Therefore it is recommended to have no more than *three* `Include`s. So I think you have to reconsider the number of `Include`s you really need. It's probably much more efficient to load associated entities in separate queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!I understand now the difference between Include an d join. As you suggested, how can I execute all `Includes` without removing some off them. Can I put them in the same object (`List<User> users`). In fact, is there a way to select only columns instead of tacking entire object.

Comment: If you want to select only some columns, which is called *projection*, you would use joins and `select new { ... }` (but then you haven't got the same as users). You can mimic `Include`s by loading related entities into the context. EF will glue it all together by _relationship fixup_. For more details, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13904825/861716).

Answer (score 1):

The joins you are using are inner joins, not left joins. You can use `DefaultIfEmpty()` to turn them into left joins, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

Also, note that using linq you are creating a *query*, not a list. The query only gets executed when the results need to be retrieved. You can call `ToList()` to do this. In general, if you are using LINQ for retrieving data it is important to read about deferred execution (good explanation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), otherwise the data you get may not be what you are expecting if it changes between the time the query is created and the time that it gets executed.

Also, for that many includes I think that using a stored procedure be easier.

Comment: I tried with toList(), it's not working I get this `cannot implicitly convert type 'system.linq.iqueryable anonymous type' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PAService.PartnerEDM.User>#1'`

Comment: I don't want to use store proc in this case. I think that ussing joins will speed up the execution.

Comment: And I have already read the two topic. I'm testing it on linqpad