# Loading virtual properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, projection

I am retrieving data from the database (with Entity Framework) using DTOs:

```
IQueryable<User> users = repository.ListFiltered<User>(n => n.Active);

var usersDTO = from user in users
               select new UserAccountDTO{
                   UserId = user.Id,
                   UserName = user.Name,
                   InstitutionName = user.Institution.Name,
                   InstitutionCountry = user.Institution.Country.Name
               };
```

I'm doing this because the **user** entity, and the **institution** entity, have a lot of data i don't need right now, so i don't want to retrieve it from the database.

But the problem is that i don't like the code, i would like to split the code and concatenate the selects, is there anyway to do this?

I'd like to arrive to something like:

```
users.LoadUserData().LoadInstitutionData();
```

What do you say? is it possible?

Comment: so `Institution` is navigational property to `User`. Why don't you simply `.Select` on your repository.ListFiltered<User>? and then do `.ToList()` in the end, coz, what you're trying to achieve is even complex and not neat

Comment: Because i don't want to retrieve all the data, i only need some fields and in some conditions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what `LoadUserData()` and  `LoadInstitutionData()` should look like. Let's say that the end product of this method chain should be an `IEnumerable<UserAccountDTO>`. The last method in fluent syntax always determines the output. So `LoadInstitutionData()` should return the required `IEnumerable`. Clear.

But what about the input? I see two alternatives:

- The input is `IEnumerable<User>` (or `IQueryable<User>`). OK, that would mean that `LoadInstitutionData()` can't do anything else than the code you already have. And that's not a solution, because you don't like the code. Moreover, the method requires that `user.Institution` and the `Country` must be loaded or lazy loadable, which is hard to express in any form of code contract.
- The input is `IEnumerable<UserAccountDTO>` in which `LoadUserData` has set the direct `user` properties and that `LoadInstitutionData` should replenish with `Institution` data. Now the question is: how should `LoadInstitutionData` do that? Anyhow, what was done in one query now will take at least two queries, maybe even 1 + n.

More complex alternatives could consist of passing and composing expressions, but surely you'll be jumping from the frying pan into the fire, reinventing LINQ's extension methods, or AutoMapper, or...

Wait, AutoMapper.

Did you know that AutoMapper could do this for you in a way that may appeal to you?

All you need is a class

```
class UserAccountDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }
    public string InstitutionCountryName { get; set; } // Notice the Name part!
};
```

A mapping

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserAccountDTO>();
```

A using:

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
```

And a concise syntax:

```
var usersDTO = users.Project().To<UserAccountDTO>();
```

(And AutoMapper from NuGet, of course).

Automapper will resolve a property like `InstitutionCountryName` as `user.Institution.Country.Name` and the result of the projection is one expression that is translated into one SQL statement with joins and all. That's code I do like.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that the property name like "InstitutionCountryName" is automagically mapped from Institution.Country.Name ? Nice feature.

Comment: Thanks! It's awesome, but what about if i have to work with collections? And what about applying filters? Is it possible? I mean... if i'd need something like **public IEnumerable<Institution> Institutions = user.Institutions.Where(n => n.Active)**

Comment: @ArielScherman AutoMapper can also fill child collections. Partially loaded collections is a different chapter. EF doesn't support that directly, but you can achieve it in more elaborate way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13904825/861716